# Get ajax loaded after go back button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, pushstate, popstate

im trying to do a website and i'm using ajax to load some content.
The problem is that when I click on my submit button, an other page is loaded, but when i come back, the ajax is not loaded anymore.I want my page to be as it was.

I know i can use pop state event to stock data and change link in history with pushState, but it doesnt work. The pop state event only work when i click on buttons, but does not work when I submit form, even if pushState is called.

Here is my code ** Commented

```
**//On those button click, pop state event work**
**// Those button calls ajax function that print content below**

<div onclick='afficheInformations("Ajax/getInternet.php")' id="boutonServices">
<a class="button" href="#informations" role="button" >
<span>Internet</span>
<div class="icon">
    <div class="fa fa-check"></div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div onclick='afficheInformations("Ajax/getTelevision.php")' id="boutonServices">
<a class="button" href="#informations" role="button">
<span>Télévision</span>
<div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="features-wrapper">
<div id="future">

//This is the content loaded after the button click, its a select that calls ajax
<center><label style="color:white">Voir votre <a style="color:red"href="Speedtest.php" target="_blank"> vitesse</a> actuelle</label></center>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="3u 12u(mobile)">
        <section>
        <table class="table">
      <tr>                                               
    <th class="fontInternet" style="color:white">Vitesse de téléchargement</th>
       </tr>
      <tr>
      <th> 

  <select id="telechargement" onchange="addInternet()">
     <option value="non selectionne">Non selectionné</option>
     <option value="1-9">1-9 Mbits/s</option>
     <option value="10-19">10-19 Mbits/s</option>
     <option value="20-49">20-49 Mbits/s</option>
     <option value="50">50+ Mbits/s</option>
  </select>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

**//Finally this is the final content loaded on my main page
//At end, there is my submit, and there is where I want the onclick to keep 
// my data saved when i come back, as I said, pop state dont work on this...**
<li class="price_block">
<form method="POST" action="Fournisseurs/'.$nom.'.php">
<h3 name="services" value="internet">'.$nom.'</h3>
<div class="price">
<div class="price_figure">
<span class="price_number">$'.$prix.'</span>
    <br>
<span class="price_tenure">par mois</span>
</div>
 </div>
 <ul class="features">
   <li>Technologie<br>'.$tech.'</li>
   <li>Téléchargement<br>'. $telechargementData.' Mb/s</li>
 </ul>
<div class="footer">
<input type="submit" onClick="pushHistorique()" class="action_button" value="Consulter" /></input>
 </form>
 </div>
</li>
```

Thats my pop state function :

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
alert("popstate");
}
```

Thats my push State function, called on my sumbit click :

```
function pushHistorique(){
history.pushState({informations: window.currentInformation}, "title",window.location.href );
 }
```

I hope this is clear, thnx for your attention, I appreciate it

Comment: your content is loaded with select? If so, how did you wrap your ajax call?

Comment: Can we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: <select id="telechargement" onchange="addInternet()">, on Change function let my call my js function to call my ajax @codemax

Comment: my website is http://fournisseursquebec.com/   You can click on internet button, then select what you want, then click on Consulter submit button, then the page is loaded, but if I want to come back, content is not loaded anymore @TinyGiant

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial? https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/